# How to create Linear Gradient in App Bar Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, gradient, android-appbarlayout, flutter-appbar

I am trying to add a linear gradient in the appBar, but so far i didnt managed how to do it.
Does anybody know how can i add this in my appBar? Thank you

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                    colors: [const Color(0xFFF06292), const Color(0xff2A75BC)]),
```

my code looks like this

```
class RegisterAgree extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RegisterAgreeState createState() => _RegisterAgreeState();
}

class _RegisterAgreeState extends State<RegisterAgree> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
        title: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.asset(
              'assets/images/logox.png',
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              height: 45.0,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: check this article, https://hackernoon.com/flutter-gradient-app-bar-jm8a32fu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create your own reusable appbar widget by wrapping an `AppBar` inside a `Container` with a gradient:

```dart
class GradientAppBar extends StatelessWidget with PreferredSizeWidget {
  static const _defaultHeight = 56.0;

  final double elevation;
  final Gradient gradient;
  final Widget title;
  final double barHeight;

  GradientAppBar(
      {this.elevation = 3.0,
      this.gradient,
      this.title,
      this.barHeight = _defaultHeight});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 56.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(gradient: gradient, boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
          offset: Offset(0, elevation),
          color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
          blurRadius: 3,
        ),
      ]),
      child: AppBar(
        title: title,
        elevation: 0.0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(barHeight);
}
```

[Try the full example on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/bf70f5a804142afe7e758362336213bb)

**Screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can also use this :

```
appBar: AppBar(

  title: Text('Flutter Demo'),
  flexibleSpace: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      gradient: LinearGradient(
        begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
        end: Alignment.centerRight,
        colors: <Color>[
          Colors.red,
          Colors.blue
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```